# Stream client android camera to android server

Tags: java, android, sockets, camera, stream

I'm trying to develop an app for an android server that receive a live video from the android client's camera. I found this project on GitHub: https://github.com/Lucklyric/android-camera-socket-stream. I need to invert client and server (client stream its camera to server).
This is for the Server:

```
public class MyServerThread implements Runnable {

private int mServerPort;
private String mServerIP;
private Handler mHandler;
private Context mContext;
private VideoActivity mActivityInstance;
String message;
private BitmapFactory.Options bitmap_options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

public MyServerThread (Context context,String serverip,int serverport,Handler handler) {
    super();
    mContext=context;
    mServerIP = serverip;
    mServerPort = serverport;
    this.mHandler = handler;
    bitmap_options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
    mActivityInstance = (VideoActivity) mContext;
}
public void run(){
    try {
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(mServerPort);
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mActivityInstance.serverStatus.setText("Listening on IP: " + mServerIP);
            }
        });
        while (true){
            final Socket s = ss.accept();

            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mActivityInstance.serverStatus.setText("Video from: " + s.getInetAddress());
                }
            });
            new Thread(new ServerSocketThread(s)).start();
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("ServerThread", "run: erro");
    }
}
public class ServerSocketThread implements Runnable{
    Socket s = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    public ServerSocketThread(Socket s) throws IOException {
        this.s = s;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            InputStream inStream = null;
            try {
                inStream = s.getInputStream();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(inStream);
            while (true) {
                try {
                    int token = is.readInt();
                    if (token == 4) {
                        if (is.readUTF().equals("#@@#")) {
                            //System.out.println("before-token" + token);
                            int imgLength = is.readInt();
                            System.out.println("getLength:" + imgLength);
                            System.out.println("back-token" + is.readUTF());
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[imgLength];
                            int len = 0;
                            while (len < imgLength) {
                                len += is.read(buffer, len, imgLength - len);
                            }
                            Message m = mHandler.obtainMessage();
                            m.obj = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(buffer, 0, buffer.length,bitmap_options);
                            if (m.obj != null) {
                                mHandler.sendMessage(m);
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("Decode Failed");
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                        Log.d("MyServerThread","Skip Dirty bytes!!!!"+Integer.toString(token));
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

This is for the Client:

```
public class MyClientThread implements Runnable{


private Handler mHandler;
Socket s;
private Context mContext;
private VideoActivity mActivityInstance;

public MyClientThread(Context context , Socket s, Handler handler){
    mContext=context;
    this.s = s;
    this.mHandler = handler;
    mActivityInstance = (VideoActivity) mContext;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    OutputStream os = null;
    try {

        s.setKeepAlive(true);
        os = s.getOutputStream();
        while(true){
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);
            dos.writeInt(4);
            dos.writeUTF("#@@#");
            dos.writeInt(mActivityInstance.mPreview.mFrameBuffer.size());
            dos.writeUTF("-@@-");
            dos.flush();
            System.out.println(mActivityInstance.mPreview.mFrameBuffer.size());
            dos.write(mActivityInstance.mPreview.mFrameBuffer.toByteArray());
            dos.flush();
            Thread.sleep(1000/15);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        try {
            if (os!= null)
                os.close();

        } catch (Exception e2) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

}

Server not upload the video and I don t know why..

Comment: Have you looked through the logcat output for clues to what is happening?

Comment: This is the error read in logcat: E/Auth: [GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl] getToken() failed. Status BAD_AUTHENTICATION, Account: <ELLIDED:-43583595>, App: com.android.vending, Service: androidmarket
    com.google.android.gms.auth.be.account.b.d: Long live credential not available.
        at com.google.android.gms.auth.be.account.b.e.a(:com.google.android.gms:105)
        at com.google.android.gms.auth.be.p.a(:com.google.android.gms:355)
        at com.google.android.gms.auth.be.o.a(:com.google.android.gms:260)

Comment: I did a web search for "[GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl] getToken() failed. Status BAD_AUTHENTICATION" and got numerous results.  Perhaps one of them will be helpful for you.